# How to write pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

i have this problem in college for this assignment and no one seems to be able to help me the question is as follows:

1.2 Write a pseudocode to represent the logic of a program that allows a user to enter an hourly pay rate and hours worked. The program outputs the user’s gross pay
 [25] 1.3 Modify the program that computes gross pay to allow the user to enter the income tax rate. The program outputs the net pay after taxes have been deducted.

I am not experienced in the IT field that well as this is my first year.

I have tried doing pseudocode but everyone whom i have taken it to review says it is wrong, but no one shows the right thing in which way i should do it.

1. start
2. initialize the known variables: max hours worked with no overtime (MAxNoOvertime). bonus rate for overtime hours (BonusRate), non taxable payroll amount (MAxNoDue), Tax rate (Due);
3. enter hours worked overtime (HoursWorked) and hourly rate (Hourrate0;
4. `if(HOurWorked -MaxNoOvertime)<=0 Then grosspay=HoursWOrked*HourRate;
   Else
   GrossPay=HourRate*(MaxNoOvertime + BonusRate* (Hoursworked - MaxNoOverTime));
   End;`

Many people are telling me that question 1.3 is suppose to be linked up with 1.2, and some are saying it vice versa. please help me

Comment: Too broad, but I haven't written pseudocode since about 1979.

Comment: 1. pseudo code is not language linked, so no reason to tag java, 2. what have you tried so far, that they say it's wrong?

Comment: i understand pseudo code isnt language linked, but many people have asked me what language we are coding in and so forth, which is why i wasnt sure and just tagged java in it, the other students arent giving me direct answers as to what is wrong, they just tell me that 1.3 needs to link to 1.2 and others say 1.2 need to link to 1.3

Answer (score 3):

Question 1.2 and 1.3 are indeed linked. Maybe I am oversimplifying but isn't it as easy as just doing the following?:

```
// 1.2
variable hoursWorked = <user entered>
variable payRate = <user entered>
variable grossPay = (hoursWorked * payRate)

output grossPay

// 1.3
variable hoursWorked = <user entered>
variable payRate = <user entered>
variable taxRate = <user entered>
variable grossPay = (hoursWorked * payRate)
variable netPay = grossPay - ((grossPay/100) * taxRate)

output netPay
```

In your assignments I don't see anything about overtime which you did include in your examples. Why did you decide to include it?

Furthermore, psuedocode is meant to convey an idea. It is not meant to be compiled and ran.

Comment: sorry about that, it was just something that i have tried and did, humble apologies for that there,

Comment: in your answer those are just the variables listed right ?

Comment: This should be everything that is asked in the assignments 1.2 and 1.3.

Comment: 100% i tried going to the lecturer to ask him about this, because our module is only based on OOP theory aspect, but they are asking us to create and code a program when we have not programmed before in our lives

Comment: the answer you gave me seems to be 100% but the question is for 25 marks is that all that there is to that pseudo code?

Comment: Psuedocode is not programming. It is writing down steps that should be performed. It is not meant to be compiled and ran. I don't really understand the link with OOP here and why you mention that. This logic could exist in any paradigm, whether it's OOP, procedural, functional, etc.

Comment: this assignment is from the OOP Module (intro to OOP)

Comment: 1.2 is the initial assignment which outputs gross pay. 1.3 is the adjusted program taken from 1.2 and outputs net pay. This is everything asked :).